# aws_launch_configuration: timeout - last error: dial tcp :22: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following launch config for an auto-scaling group:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ASG-launch-config" {
  #name = "ASG-launch-config"  # see: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3665
  name_prefix = "ASG-launch-config-"
  image_id = "ami-a4dc46db" #Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
  #image_id = "ami-b70554c8" #Amazon Linux 2
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.WEB-DMZ.id}"]
  key_name = "MyEC2KeyPair"
  #user_data = <<-EOF
  #            #!/bin/bash
  #            echo "Hello, World" > index.html
  #            nohup busybox httpd -f -p "${var.server_port}" &
  #          EOF


  provisioner "file" {
  source="script.sh"
  destination="/tmp/script.sh"
  }
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline=[
  "chmod +x /tmp/script.sh",
  "sudo /tmp/script.sh"
  ]
  }
  connection {
  user="ubuntu"
  private_key="${file("MyEC2KeyPair.pem")}"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

- aws_launch_configuration.ASG-launch-config: timeout - last error: dial tcp :22: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I want to run a bash script to basically install WordPress on the instances created.
the script runs fine in a resource type "aws_instance" "example"

how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the instance is denying your traffic. Start up an instance without the provisioning script and see if you can SSH to it using the key you provided. You may want to add verbose logging to the SSH command with `-v`.